# Issue launching Spring webapp on JBoss

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jboss

When i trying to deploy my project, this presents a problem with the bean, i have not been able to solve it, i attach the error and the class that generates it. I need help to solve this please.
I thank you in advance.

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

> Field sender in co.com.coomeva.golden.service.ws.main.GreetingController required a bean of type 'co.com.coomeva.golden.service.ws.jms.DistributorSender' that could not be found.
>   The injection point has the following annotations:- @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
>   Action:Consider defining a bean of type 'co.com.coomeva.golden.service.ws.jms.DistributorSender' in your configuration.
>   22:41:15,280 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./Golden: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./Golden: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'greetingController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sender'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'co.com.coomeva.golden.service.ws.jms.DistributorSender' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>       at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:84)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>       at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'greetingController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sender'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'co.com.coomeva.golden.service.ws.jms.DistributorSender' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>       at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:241)
>       at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:99)
>       at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:81)
>       ... 6 more

```
    package co.com.coomeva.golden.service.ws.main;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import co.com.coomeva.golden.service.ws.jms.*;
import co.com.coomeva.golden.service.ws.model.GoldenResponse;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = { "co.com.coomeva.golden.service.ws.controllers", "co.com.coomeva.golden.service.ws.jms.DistributorSender"})
public class GoldenServiceApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(applicationClass, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(applicationClass);
    }

    private static Class<GoldenServiceApplication> applicationClass = GoldenServiceApplication.class;
}

@RestController
class GreetingController {

    @Autowired
    private DistributorSender sender;

    @PostMapping("/distributor/records")
    public GoldenResponse setGoldenRecord(@RequestBody String goldenRecord) {
        GoldenResponse response = new GoldenResponse();

        try {
            sender.publishMessage(goldenRecord);
            response.setCode(HttpStatus.OK.value());
            response.setMessage("Golden Record Published");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            String error = e.getCause().toString();
            error = error.length() > 200 ? error.substring(0, 200) : error;
            response.setMessage("Golden Record was not published. Error:" + error);
        }

        return response;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/hello/{name}")
    String hello(@PathVariable String name) {
        return "Hello, " + name + "!";
    }

    @GetMapping("/Example2")
    public GoldenResponse exampleDist() {
        GoldenResponse goldenResponse = new GoldenResponse();
        goldenResponse.setCode(1);
        goldenResponse.setMessage("sd");
        System.out.println("Vinagre");
        return goldenResponse;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I reproduced your issue. Below are the changes you need to make:

1. `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages ={"co.com.coomeva.golden.service.ws.jms","co.com.coomeva.golden.service.ws.main"})`
2. You need to make your `DistributorSender` class spring aware with an
   annotation like `@Component` or `@Repository`.

GoldenServiceApplication.java

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"co.com.coomeva.golden.service.ws.jms","co.com.coomeva.golden.service.ws.main"})
public class GoldenServiceApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer 
{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(applicationClass, args);
}

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(applicationClass);
}

private static Class<GoldenServiceApplication> applicationClass = 
GoldenServiceApplication.class;
}

@RestController
class GreetingController {

@Autowired
private DistributorSender sender;

@PostMapping("/distributor/records")
public GoldenResponse setGoldenRecord(@RequestBody String goldenRecord) 
{
    GoldenResponse response = new GoldenResponse();

    try {
        sender.publishMessage(goldenRecord);
        response.setCode(HttpStatus.OK.value());
        response.setMessage("Golden Record Published");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        String error = e.getCause().toString();
        error = error.length() > 200 ? error.substring(0, 200) : error;
        response.setMessage("Golden Record was not published. Error:" + error);
    }

    return response;
}

@RequestMapping("/hello/{name}")
String hello(@PathVariable String name) {
    return "Hello, " + name + "!";
}

@GetMapping("/Example2")
public GoldenResponse exampleDist() {
    GoldenResponse goldenResponse = new GoldenResponse();
    goldenResponse.setCode(1);
    goldenResponse.setMessage("sd");
    System.out.println("Vinagre");
    return goldenResponse;
    }

}
```

and DistributorSender.java

```
package co.com.coomeva.golden.service.ws.jms;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class DistributorSender {
private String record;

public void publishMessage(String record) {
    this.record = record;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A good practice for Spring-boot applications:

Store your Application class (the one that has the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation) on the main package, and put all other `*.java` files under this package, so Spring Application could find them.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove unnecessary annotation,`@ComponentScan`,`@Configuration` and `@EnableAutoConfiguration`

Only below given code is sufficient to run your application until you have any specific requirement.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class GoldenServiceApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(applicationClass, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(applicationClass);
    }

    private static Class<GoldenServiceApplication> applicationClass = GoldenServiceApplication.class;
}
```